# Exact YEAR from DATE in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database

I'm trying to get names of person with at least birthday 1950.

```
  SELECT Person.names...
 ..WHERE SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM Person.dateOfBirth) => 1950;
```

What is wrong with this query?

Comment: You are selecting the birthyear. Whereas you should get it by substracting the sysdate from the birthdate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `YEAR()` function will return the year from a `DATETIME` field in MySQL as an integer.

```
SELECT Person.names FROM Person WHERE YEAR(Person.dateOfBirth) >= 1950;
```